# Do not allow visits on haproxy IP address

Tags: haproxy

I have a haproxy running on ip 1.2.3.4. It hosts about 10 website domains. If i go to http://1.2.3.4 it apparently goes to one of those 10 domains but i don't want it to do that. I want it to give an error or something. How can i do this?

Comment: No you don't. That entire IP range is reserved and currently cannot be allocated because of all the unwanted traffic caused by people putting that address in places where it doesn't belong such as this post. There are 79228162514264337593543951104 IP addresses reserved for use in examples. This [meta post](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/6063/214507) has more advice about that.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that 1.2.3.4 is a placeholder IP, as it would not work to serve actual traffic (other than locally, if you butcher your local network config to do so), and most people are not going to publish their actual public IP in a question like this. If downvotes are for another reason besides this detail that's not at all relevant to the question being asked, you should explain -- especially given this is a brand new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have one backend configured for each domain. You basically just have to configure matching via host header (which you're probably already doing), and then configure a default backend that serves all other traffic.

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    mode http

    # match host headers
    acl host_one hdr(host) -i one.example.com
    acl host_two hdr(host) -i two.example.com
    # ..
    acl host_ten hdr(host) -i ten.example.com

    # map to backends
    use_backend backend_one if host_one
    use_backend backend_two if host_two
    # ..
    use_backend backend_ten if host_ten

    # all unmatched hosts fallback to default
    default_backend backend_default
```

If you want this backend to serve an error, you can do so by using the [http-request deny](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4-http-request) directive:

```
backend backend_default
    errorfile 403 /var/www/403.http
    http-request deny deny_status 403
```

Note you're limited to the error codes supported by [errorfile](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#errorfile) which are 200, 400, 403, 405, 408, 429, 500, 502, 503, and 504.